# Servos wont track face due to being stuck in another function

Tags: python, arduino, servo

My code is simple, when Serial.available() is equal to 0, meaning that no data is coming through, execute function **something()**. But when Serial.read() gets any other number, this means that face is detected and it should stop executing function **something()** and start tracking face, execute function **track().**

When I run the code, and the camera detects no face, it does as I want it to, the servo rotate back and forth. But as soon as it detects a face, the servo ignores to move with the face and continues to run the **something()** function.

How do I get it to just follow my face when detected, and then go back to rotating back and forth when no face is detected. if I get rid of the **something()** function, the code works fine and the servos move in respect to the position of my face. But when I add in the **something()** function, it does not leave that function, even when face if detected.

*.ino

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo servoVer; //Vertical Servo
Servo servoHor; //Horizontal Servo
int x;
int y;
int prevX;
int prevY;
int pos = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  servoVer.attach(5); //Attach Vertical Servo to Pin 5
  servoHor.attach(6); //Attach Horizontal Servo to Pin 6
  servoVer.write(90);
  servoHor.write(90);
} 

void Pos()
{
  if (prevX != x || prevY != y)
  {
    int servoX = map(x, 450, 0, 0, 180);
    int servoY = map(y, 450, 0, 180, 0);
    servoX = min(servoX, 180);
    servoX = max(servoX, 0);
    servoY = min(servoY, 180);
    servoY = max(servoY, 0);
    servoHor.write(servoX);
    servoVer.write(servoY);
  }
}

void something(){
   for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    servoHor.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(5);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}

void track(){
    if(Serial.available() > 0);
    {
      if (Serial.read() == 'X')
      {
        x = Serial.parseInt();
        if (Serial.read() == 'Y')
        {
          y = Serial.parseInt();
          Pos();
        }
      }
      while (Serial.available() > 0)
      {
        Serial.read();
      }
    }
  }

void loop()
{
  if ( ! Serial.available() ) 
  {
    something();
  }
  else
  {
    track();
  }
}
```

*.py

```
import numpy as np
import serial
import time
import sys
import cv2

arduino = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
time.sleep(2)
print("Connection to arduino...")


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img,1)
    cv2.resizeWindow('img', 500,500)
    cv2.line(img,(500,250),(0,250),(0,255,0),1)
    cv2.line(img,(250,0),(250,500),(0,255,0),1)
    cv2.circle(img, (250, 250), 5, (255, 255, 255), -1)
    gray  = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),5)
        roi_gray  = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        arr = {y:y+h, x:x+w}
        print (arr)

        print ('X :' +str(x))
        print ('Y :'+str(y))
        print ('x+w :' +str(x+w))
        print ('y+h :' +str(y+h))

        xx = int((x+(x+h))/2)
        yy = int((y+(y+w))/2)

        print (xx)
        print (yy)

        center = (xx,yy)

        print("Center of Rectangle is :", center)
        data = "X{0:d}Y{1:d}Z".format(xx, yy)
        print ("output = '" +data+ "'")
        # arduino.write(data)
        arduino.write(data.encode())

    cv2.imshow('img',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the serial connection between, what ever running the python code, and the arduino are working?

Comment: Yes @XerXeX, if I get rid of the something() function, the track() function works fine and the servos begin to move in respect to the position of my face.

Comment: I'm surprised your sketch compiles at all. You have a extra ";" in your "track()" function at "if(Serial.available() > 0);
    {" try to remove it. Don't know if it will change anything.

Comment: If your servo can reach the commanded position in 5 milliseconds, I'd love to learn the part number.  Almost certainly it won't do that.

Comment: @XerXeX,@TomServo. I removed the ";" within track() and the output is the same but something new has now happened. The servoHor continues to execute the something() function, but when my face is detected the servoVer is seen to track my face. So my servoHor is stuck in the something() function, while my servoVer is in the track() function. This might be because the servo is not busy executing the something() function. But it is all structured within an IF statement so how are both functions being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple problems with your code.

1. It will always return to `something()` because your arduino code runs faster than your python code, so your arduino checks for the `Serial.available()` more often than the python code can output a new character. Therefore, when it don't see a new character in the buffer it will return to `something()`. Try to add a small delay in the `track()` function in the end to overcome this.
2. You never update `prevX` and `prevY`, therefore `if (prevX != x || prevY != y)` is executed every time. Also this part 

   `servoX = min(servoX, 180);
   servoX = max(servoX, 0);
   servoY = min(servoY, 180);
   servoY = max(servoY, 0);`

   really isn't doing anything, it will always output the originally value of `serveoX` and `servoY`

But find out how long the python code takes to execute and add a delay a little longer than that in the `track()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much, it does exactly what i wanted, I really want to understand whats going on though, do you mind explaining how adding a delay to track() solved this because this function relays on data from python to work which you said takes long than my arduino code, so how does adding a delay to it allow it to now work.

Comment: One more thing, not a big problem but the servo's do not move as smooth now that the something() function has been implemented into the code, is this normal?

Comment: Is it the `track()`function or the `something()`function that isn't smooth?

Comment: The track() function, it moves with a bit of a stutter.